# Confirm dialog box in swing with two buttons

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Following is my swing program code

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
public class OptionPaneExample extends WindowAdapter{  
JFrame f;  
OptionPaneExample(){  
    f=new JFrame();   
    f.addWindowListener(this);  
    f.setSize(300, 300);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);  
    f.setVisible(true);  
}  
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
    int a=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,"Are you sure?");  
if(a==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){  
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
}  
}  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    new  OptionPaneExample();  
}     
}
```

In output i want only two buttons Yes and No. But in output i'm getting cancel button. How to remove that please let me know.

[I'm getting this output. But i want only two buttons Yes and No.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6CTy.png)

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
int a=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,"Are you sure?", "Question", YES_NO_OPTION );
```

Please read the documentation for [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

Comment: 0 for yes, 1 for no

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f, "Your Message", "Title on Box", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```